# Should setting `checkbox.checked = false` not clear the HTML attribute too?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox3.5

Here's my HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" checked="">
```

Here's a Firebug excerpt:

```
>>> test
<input id="test" type="checkbox" checked="">

>>> test.checked = false
false

>>> test
<input id="test" type="checkbox" checked="">
```

Um...am I missing something, or should that last line not read the following?

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox">
```

UI-wise, the checkbox does indeed uncheck when I execute the `checked = false` line.

Anyway, if there's some legitimate explanation for this, then what's the proper way to uncheck a checkbox from JavaScript, if not `checked = false`?

Comment: You probably should not care what Firebug says as long as the data gets to your server and the UI behaves as expected.

Comment: This is just to demonstrate what I'm talking about.  The real problem is that I have CSS that I want to have an effect based on whether the checkbox is checked or not, and it only does its job when I click the checkbox, not when I set `.checked`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `value` attribute of `input type="text"` and the `checked` or `selected` attributes of `input type="checkbox"`, `radio` and `option` correspond to the initial value of the form field, **not** the current value the user or script has set. Consequently changing the `checked` property does not alter the attribute value, and setting the `checked` attribute does not alter the real visible value that's going to be submitted with the form.

The `checked="checked"` attribute corresponds to the `defaultChecked` [DOM property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-20509171), not the `checked` property. Similarly, the `value="..."` attribute corresponds to `defaultValue`.

(Note there are IE gotchas here due to IE not knowing the difference between a property and an attribute.)

Comment: I never mentioned the `value` attribute.  My test checkbox doesn't even have one.  So I'm not sure how your first paragraph applies, but the defaultChecked property was key.  Thanks!

Comment: It's background: checked/defaultChecked is the special case of value/defaultValue for checkboxes (similarly selected/defaultSelected for options).

Comment: Kev, your question is about what is being reported by Firebug.  The entirety of bobince's original answer is relevant.  Also, additional information is never bad.

Comment: Please read my question and show me where I mention the `value` attribute. As for Firebug see my comment on the question.

Answer (score -2):

You may be expecting Firebug to display value information similarly to how `style` is updated in the *HTML* inspection pane.  However, `input`, `select`, `option`, and `textarea` do not behave the same way and values will not be updated in this pane and will always display the original values (those at page render time).  If the UI is updating, then you know you're doing it right.

Comment: This just isn't true.  Try it yourself with an HTML element `a` with no value attribute--run the lines `a`, `a.value=7`, and `a` again.

Comment: Sorry, what I said still stands, but I should clarify that `a` was a JavaScript variable pointing to an HTML `input` elemnt.  It probably came across as if I meant an anchor tag.

Comment: It did come across that way, but I've delete that comment as it is no longer necessary.  However, I don't understand the scenario that you are trying to describe in your first comment, particularly with "and `a` again"

Comment: I sure get confused with this comment deletion...makes it difficult to understand the ones that remain.  Anyway, the second time you execute `a` on the firebug command line is to see the difference in `a` that `a.value=7` made...

Answer (score -3):

`checked = ''`, is correct I believe.  I suspect the browser is trying to be friendly when you do `checked = false` and doing the equivalent action, `checked = ''`.

Comment: Tried it.  Doesn't seem to change the outcome.  Also according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/checkbox , the checked property is a boolean type.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused.  Is something not working how you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I had tried to express that in the question.  I expect setting the `.checked` property to have an effect on the HTML attribute (especially since it has an effect on the UI.)  But the HTML attribute does not change, no matter what it's initially set to.  This seems pretty inconsistent.

Comment: @Kev: make sure you're looking at the right documentation. You linked to the XUL docs there.

Comment: @nickf: Oops, you're absolutely right!  In the right docs ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input ) it's the same, though.